# Insert records in chunk to mysql view

Tags: php, mysql, view, insert, database-view

I have created empty view with following query:

```
CREATE VIEW `test` AS select * from `configurations` where 0;
```

Consider `configurations` table have 100 records with primary key `id` starting from `0` to `100`.

I would like to insert data in view with chunk of `10` within loop.

I could not get any solution for the same. Can anyone give a bit of hint.

**Update:**
Following steps I want to perform.

1. Create empty view (I achieved this)
2. I have base table with 100 records in it.
3. Now, I want my view to represent any `10` records based on `id` like [`where id IN (1,5,8,3,6,67,34,23,45,99)`]
4. Again after some operations I would like more 10 records to be selected from base table. like [`where id IN (11,55,88,33,66,27,43,23,15,19)`]

Hope I am clear enough.

Comment: Your question is confusing, please confirm if you are trying to "export data out of your view" or "insert data into the table used by your view"? Views do no store data of their own. Also, "where 0" doesn't appear to be helpful - what is that supposed to achieve? Surely that just means your view will always be empty?

Comment: @puppyFlo please check my update.

Comment: I guess this can not be possible as `view` will be created initially with the data retrieved using condition applied initially. It is representation of data. It's not physical table so that I can not periodically insert more data in it. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 0):

OK, I'll try again.

This is a misinterpreation of what a view does - a view should be used to inspect existing data from actual table(s) in a fixed manner such that a view could be used to show all configurations with ID value less than 25 etc.

What you have described sounds like all you need to do is issue selects to your main table with a different list of ID's to retrieve.

Is there any reason you aren't doing this:

```
SELECT * FROM configurations WHERE id in (1,4,6,7,8,9);
SELECT * FROM configurations WHERE id in (5,51,2,45,6);
```

?

**EDIT:**

Add a column to your configuration table as an "in view" indicator. Update your view to only display records where in_view = 1. Then simply update the configurations table and set those interesting records to in_view=1

Hope that helps?

Comment: I have millions of records in `configurations` table and I want to store suppose some records (which meet my calculations) in view. So I start processing with a chunk of 1000 records at a moment and perform calculations on each of them and if they meet my need then I would like to add them to `view`. So at a moment while creating view, I can not do like `where in()` As I have millions of records and that might not fits to IN() clause.

Comment: @Parixit - it sounds like you don't want a view at all, what you want is another table to store a subset of your configurations. This may sound incorrect as you don't want to copy your data however it meets your requirements to deal with chucks of the source data. You are correct that updating the view with huge IN statements is not good practice. As an alternative suggestion perhaps you could add a tinyint column to your configurations table, calling it "in_view" or similar and then simply make your view show all records where that column is set to 1 - how does that sound?